# A database > with the same name exists (Visual studio 2015, Vb.net, local DB)

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

my connection string is:

```
con.ConnectionString = " Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=true;"
```

my app.config is :

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="materials_summury.My.MySettings.Database1ConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

but I got the error message :

> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file
>   C:\Users\example\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\materials
>   summury\materials summury\bin\Debug\ Database1.mdf failed. A database
>   with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it
>   is located on UNC share.

can you please help ? I'm under VS 2015 express it's a localdb.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you hardcoding a connection AND using it in the app.config? The config file exists so you don't have the connection string coded over and over again.

Comment: thanks for your answer Sean Lange, because I want a relative path not something like C:\...

Comment: huh? You have a value hard coded and it matches exactly what is in your config file. Perhaps your question is not well formed here. I am not a fan of attaching an mdf file anyway. I would much prefer to have a sql server and connect to it.

Comment: I don't know what to do, can you help me out ? I wanna only connect my program with tha database but I still stuck with this problem

Comment: Well from what you have posted it seems you are trying to attach the same mdf multiple times. You can't do that. If you are going to continually attach like this you will also have to continually detach. The downside is that it takes time to attach and detach a database all the time.

Comment: it's a localdb generated by Visual studio, I don't know why I'm getting this problem. but when I use the path :C:\Users\example\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\materials summury\Rexnord materials summury\Database1.mdf instead of datadirectory the app works just fine

Comment: You have a blank space between \ and the D in `Database1.mdf`, which results in a filename of `\ Database1.mdf`. Is your file really named `" Database1.mdf"`

Comment: Thanks Ken White I removed the blank. the app is working just post you answer I'm gonna aprrove it if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have what looks to be an embedded space in your connection string between `\` and `Database1.mdf`:

```
AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ Database1.mdf
                                 |
                                 |
                                 Note the space
```

Unless your database is really named " Database1.mdf", I'd suspect that it's causing the issue you're experiencing.